# Angular 2 - How passing parameters to abstract service

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components, angular2-http, angular2-modules

Angular 2 - How passing parameters to abstract service when I provide service in module

File with abstract service

```js
@Injectable()
export class Service<T>{
    private headers: RequestOptions = headersRequest.options;
    private readonly baseUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: Http, baseUrl: string) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public get(id: number): Promise<T> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }
}
```

File with module when I provide service

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderTennisComponent,
        TennisComponent,
        ProgramsComponent,
        ProgramComponent,
        PlotsComponent,
        GuidesComponent,
        CategoriesComponent,
        ChampionsComponent
    ],
    providers: [Service]
})
```

File with component when I use service.

```js
export class ProgramComponent implements OnInit {
    private program: IProgram;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private tennisService: Service<IProgram>) {
        //
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.getProgram(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    }

    private getProgram(id: number) {
        this.tennisService.get(id).then(
            (program) => this.program = program
        );
    }
}
```

I need passing baseUrl when I provide service.

Comment: What is the question? It looks like you are passing params to your service methods in your ProgramComponent

Comment: What or where is the abstract service? Are you talking about the generic type parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Angular DI doesn't have direct support for generics.

There are several ways to work around, depending on your requirements:

```ts
providers: [
  {provide: 'baseUrl': useValue: 'http://example.com'},
  {provide: Service, useFactory: (http, baseUrl) new Service<IProgram>(http, baseUrl), deps: [Http, new Inject('baseUrl') },
  {provide: 'ServiceIProgram', useFactory: (http, baseUrl) new Service<IProgram>(http, baseUrl), deps: [Http, new Inject('baseUrl') },
  {provide: 'Service', useFactory: (http, baseUrl) => (T) => new Service<T>(http, baseUrl), deps: [Http, new Inject('baseUrl')]
]
```

```ts
@Injectable()
export class Service<T>{

    ...

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('baseUrl') baseUrl: string ) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }
```

```ts
export class ProgramComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
       @Inject(Service) private tennisService: Service<IProgram>, // fixed type parameter
       @Inject('ServiceIProgram') private tennisService: Service<IProgram>,

       @Inject('Service') serviceFactory:any // factory to instantiate yourself
    ) {
        // not sure if passing generic type parameters this way is supported by TypeScript
        this.tennisService = serviceFactory(IProgram);
    }
```